Frequent 'USB Not Recognized' Error Pop-Up in Windows
USB Device Not Recognized Pop-Up Appears Frequently on My Windows 11 PC, Even When No USB Device is Connected. Disabling the Root Hub Stops the Issue, But It Also Affects Internal Devices like Webcam and Microphone. Can Anyone Help?



Has Windows ever been clean installed on the laptop and if so, were the CPU chipset drivers installed first, prior to any other drivers, software, or Windows Updates immediately upon exiting OOBE? This sounds like a CPU chipset driver issue when it's affecting other components besides USB ports, and while you can try running the chipset driver install package, it's unlikely to fix the issue since they must be the very first thing installed after a clean install.

I get the factory installed windows 10 and later it upgraded to windows 11, usb ports are working, but this pop up shows frequently with alert sound

Is there a trigger that starts it?  Does it happen straight after boot?

Straight after boot.

If you look at the Event Viewer do you see any errors/messages that correspond to the disconnects? Have you checked for an installed any updated drivers or firmware from your system manufacturer? If you disconnect all the USB devices, do you still get this issue?
